# Issues with SmartWizard - jQuery

Tags: jquery, slider, smart-wizard

I am using a [smart wizard](http://www.techlaboratory.net/products.php?product=smartwizard) plugin in my web page (version 0.98).
[Here](http://www.funcampuses.com/rate/harvard-university) is my web page:

I have two issues:
1) Each of the "tabs" on the wizard has a different content height. Therefore, I want the wizard to be resized height-wize when a new tab is selected. I assigned each tab div with a height attribute (I called it wizard-height), and created a JS function that resizes the entire wizard div when a new tab is selected. The problem is that the height seems to vary between browsers and resolutions, so even though it works perfectly on my Mac in Chrome, the the height doesn't get set properly on a PC (the content gets cut).
2) I am also using the select to UI slider plugin for jQuery  for my sliders. Unfortunately, as of tab number 2 in my wizard, the labels under the slider are not centered any more, but aligned to the right - this only happens as of the second wizard tab, no matter the content.

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

1) what you want to do is set the heights of all the relevant div's to 100%.
2) the reason behind this is that the ui-slider-label objects on the second wizard forward are not visible, and therefore jQuery.width return 0 on them. Read this: http://www.foliotek.com/devblog/getting-the-width-of-a-hidden-element-with-jquery-using-width/